# XCode: how to get the email of the user programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, email

I would like to avoid to ask my user to fill in a field with his email (long and discouraging). Is there a way to get the email of the user in order to avoid that he has to write it ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: from where you want to get email and where you want to keep the same ? please elaborate...

Comment: It might not be possible as you want to do it, otherwise it would be really easy for unscrupulous programmers to get the email addresses of users without permission.

Answer (score 2):

Ask first time, make user select remember me option through `UISwitch`, save it inside a plist (ENCRYPT and then SAVE IT). Next time read the plist. If user like to write every time then good for them, else they can user your given option to save it and then later you can complete the field automatically!

Comment: This is also good for people with multiple active email addresses. They can choose the one that they want to use.

Comment: I even implemented it in the way that when they start typing their first few chars it auto fills the textfield. But in my case the application was going to be used by multiple user and the company's policy on sharing username was lenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the apple ID email, then you cannot access it, you will have to ask the email explicitly